# Smack MamManager throws exception while fetching archived messages

Tags: java, android, chat, openfire, smack

I am trying to get the archived messages using below code as described in [this](http://download.igniterealtime.org/smack/docs/latest/documentation/extensions/mam.html) document

```
try {
            MamManager mamManager = MamManager.getInstanceFor(connection);
            boolean isSupported = mamManager.isSupportedByServer();
            if (isSupported) {
                MamManager.MamQueryResult mamQueryResult = mamManager.queryArchive(500);
                List<Forwarded> forwardedMessages = mamQueryResult.forwardedMessages;
                Forwarded d = forwardedMessages.get(0);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

But it's throwing `org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException$XMPPErrorException: XMPPError: feature-not-implemented - cancel` exception on executing `queryArchive()` function. Does anyone have any idea how to resolve this issue? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is resolved now after updating openfire server to latest version (4.1.5)